# DC/OS schedule container updates

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon, dcos

Is it possible to use DC/OS or Marathon to repeatedly check when a new container image update is available and update the live containers in the cluster? I'd like to avoid having Docker Hub be aware of the cluster and implementing web hooks... versus the cluster just check for image updates via a job.

Answer (score 2):

Marathon doesn't do this.

If you want polling, however, you could try using custom scheduled jobs with Metronome (built into DC/OS 1.8) or Chronos. Poll for dockerhub image updates and use the Marathon API to trigger app updates.

Comment: "Poll for dockerhub image updates and use the Marathon API"
Can you provide an example? I'm a little confused on how that fits together.

Comment: You'll have to poll a docker registry, like docker hub, using the API: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#/detail
I'm not familiar enough with the registry API to know how to detect an image update tho.